# Is there a solution to the error that WidgetConfig already exists when creating a website search in Vertex AI Search?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When creating an application to search a website in Vertex AI Search and Conversation, I get an error that WidgetConfig already exists and cannot create the application.

The specific error message is

```
WidgetConfig with name "projects/XXXXX/locations/global/collections/default_collection/engines/{app_name}/widgetConfigs/default_search_widget_config" already exists.
```

I thought I could work around this problem by creating an application with a different name, but this did not solve the problem and I got the same error.

Someone would have any idea ?

Thanks in advance